# Abort Dynamic Evaluation error

Tags: dynamic, version-10, interpreter, entity

I have been trying to run the example for geographic visualization at:

[Density of Library Books in the United States](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geographic-visualization/plot-the-density-of-library-books-in-the-united-st.html)

The first two lines of this code are:

```
allLibraries=EntityValue["PublicLibrary","Entities"];

cities=EntityValue[allLibraries,EntityProperty["PublicLibrary","City"]];
```

Here the "City" string is actually an entity (in orange box), so to enter this I have to press Ctrl-=, type "City", then press Enter. When I do this I get the error message:

[image: Abort Dynamic Evaluation]

I have tried waiting, but no matter how long I wait, there is no response.

I have also tried entering `Interpreter["City"]` instead of using the control-equals box and that did not work either.

How can get this example to work?

Note that my internet connectivity is fine and passes the built-in Mathematica connectivity test.

Also, the first line in the program, beginning with `allLibraries=...`, evaluates, but takes about a minute and a half to do so, which seems excessive to me.